# python error with devstack

Tags: django, python-2.7, openstack, devstack

can someone help me with this error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "openstack_dashboard.settings"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py", line 67, in handle
        basedirs.extend(upath(path) for path in settings.LOCALE_PATHS)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
    +lib/horizon:configure_horizon:1           exit_trap
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  local r=1
    ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  jobs -p
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  jobs=
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:514                  [[ -n '' ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:520                  '[' -f /tmp/tmp.rvJ6EFfCY3 ']'
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:521                  rm /tmp/tmp.rvJ6EFfCY3
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  kill_spinner
    +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:424               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:527                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:528                  echo 'Error on exit'
    Error on exit
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:530                  type -p generate-subunit
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  generate-subunit 1519055792 418 fail
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:533                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
    World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2018-02-19-160331.txt for details
    +./stack.sh:exit_trap:545                  exit 1
```

i'm runnig devstack (a minimal version of openstack) and when i run the ./stack.sh i get error with python2.7 (django)

Thank you

Comment: Are you using the master branch? You should try to switch to a stable branch. Sometimes, the master branch is not stable. As you can see here, in the `openstack-dashboard.settings`, it is messing `SECRET_KEY`

Comment: i think i'm using the master branch,

Comment: how about switching to `stable/pike`